# Getting "DB Error: syntax error" When searching for Deleted cases

Tags: error, civicase, search

When I try and do any kind of search for cases and I select the box for "deleted cases" I get a page saying: *DB Error: syntax error*

I am using Civi 5.3.1 and Drupal 7.59.

The log gives the following error:

```
    Aug 26 11:16:52  [info] $backTrace = #0 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(232): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 [internal function](): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): call_user_func((Array:2), Object(DB_Error))
#3 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB.php(985): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: syntax error", -2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civi...")
#4 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-2, 16, (Array:2), "SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civi...")
#5 [internal function](): PEAR->_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civi...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#6 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(224): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:8))
#7 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#8 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1905): PEAR->raiseError(NULL, -2, NULL, NULL, "SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civi...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#9 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(933): DB_common->raiseError(-2, NULL, NULL, NULL, "1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that correspon...")
#10 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(403): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#11 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1216): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civi...")
#12 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2415): DB_common->query("SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civi...")
#13 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1607): DB_DataObject->_query("SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civi...")
#14 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(415): DB_DataObject->query("SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civi...")
#15 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1371): CRM_Core_DAO->query("SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civi...", TRUE)
#16 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/BAO/Case.php(1591): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civi...")
#17 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Selector/Search.php(368): CRM_Case_BAO_Case::getNextScheduledActivity((Array:3), "upcoming")
#18 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(420): CRM_Case_Selector_Search->getRows(4, 0, 50, Object(CRM_Utils_Sort), 1, NULL)
#19 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Selector/Controller.php(340): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->getRows(Object(CRM_Core_Selector_Controller))
#20 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Case/Form/Search.php(307): CRM_Core_Selector_Controller->run()
#21 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(466): CRM_Case_Form_Search->postProcess()
#22 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Refresh.php(75): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#23 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Refresh->perform(Object(CRM_Case_Form_Search), "refresh")
#24 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Case_Form_Search), "refresh")
#25 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("refresh")
#26 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Core_Controller->run((Array:3), NULL)
#27 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:14))
#28 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#29 /sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#30 [internal function](): civicrm_invoke("case", "search")
#31 /includes/menu.inc(527): call_user_func_array("civicrm_invoke", (Array:2))
#32 /index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#33 {main}
```

EDIT:

Query that is causing the error is:

```
Aug 26 11:16:52  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -2
    [message] => DB Error: syntax error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civicrm_contact.id as contact_id, civicrm_contact.sort_name as sort_name, civicrm_phone.phone as phone, civicrm_contact.contact_type as contact_type, civicrm_contact.contact_sub_type as contact_sub_type, t_act.activity_type_id, c_type.title as case_type, civicrm_case.case_type_id as case_type_id, cov_status.label as case_status, cov_status.label as case_status_name, t_act.status_id, civicrm_case.start_date as case_start_date, case_relation_type.label_b_a as case_role, t_act.desired_date as case_scheduled_activity_date, t_act.id as case_scheduled_activity_id, t_act.act_type_name as case_scheduled_activity_type_name, t_act.act_type AS case_scheduled_activity_type  FROM civicrm_case
                  INNER JOIN civicrm_case_contact ON civicrm_case.id = civicrm_case_contact.case_id
                  INNER JOIN civicrm_contact ON civicrm_case_contact.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id  INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT case_id, act.id, activity_date_time AS desired_date, activity_type_id, status_id, aov.name AS act_type_name, aov.label AS act_type
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM civicrm_view_case_activity_upcoming
      ORDER BY activity_date_time ASC, id ASC
      ) AS upcomingOrdered
    ) AS act
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group aog ON aog.name='activity_type'
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value aov ON ( aov.option_group_id = aog.id AND aov.value = act.activity_type_id )
) AS t_act

        ON t_act.case_id = civicrm_case.id
 LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone ON (civicrm_phone.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id AND civicrm_phone.is_primary=1)
 LEFT JOIN civicrm_relationship case_relationship
 ON ( case_relationship.contact_id_a = civicrm_case_contact.contact_id AND case_relationship.contact_id_b = 4197
      AND case_relationship.case_id = civicrm_case.id )

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_relationship_type case_relation_type
 ON ( case_relation_type.id = case_relationship.relationship_type_id
      AND case_relation_type.id = case_relationship.relationship_type_id )

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_case_type c_type
 ON civicrm_case.case_type_id = c_type.id

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group cog_status
 ON cog_status.name = 'case_status'

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value cov_status
 ON ( civicrm_case.status_id = cov_status.value
      AND cog_status.id = cov_status.option_group_id )
 WHERE (1) AND  civicrm_case_contact.contact_id IN( 1502 )
 AND civicrm_case.id IN( 41)
 AND civicrm_case.is_deleted     = 1  GROUP BY case_id  ORDER BY case_scheduled_activity_date ASC 1 [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 39]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civicrm_contact.id as contact_id, civicrm_contact.sort_name as sort_name, civicrm_phone.phone as phone, civicrm_contact.contact_type as contact_type, civicrm_contact.contact_sub_type as contact_sub_type, t_act.activity_type_id, c_type.title as case_type, civicrm_case.case_type_id as case_type_id, cov_status.label as case_status, cov_status.label as case_status_name, t_act.status_id, civicrm_case.start_date as case_start_date, case_relation_type.label_b_a as case_role, t_act.desired_date as case_scheduled_activity_date, t_act.id as case_scheduled_activity_id, t_act.act_type_name as case_scheduled_activity_type_name, t_act.act_type AS case_scheduled_activity_type  FROM civicrm_case
                  INNER JOIN civicrm_case_contact ON civicrm_case.id = civicrm_case_contact.case_id
                  INNER JOIN civicrm_contact ON civicrm_case_contact.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id  INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT case_id, act.id, activity_date_time AS desired_date, activity_type_id, status_id, aov.name AS act_type_name, aov.label AS act_type
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM civicrm_view_case_activity_upcoming
      ORDER BY activity_date_time ASC, id ASC
      ) AS upcomingOrdered
    ) AS act
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group aog ON aog.name='activity_type'
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value aov ON ( aov.option_group_id = aog.id AND aov.value = act.activity_type_id )
) AS t_act

        ON t_act.case_id = civicrm_case.id
 LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone ON (civicrm_phone.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id AND civicrm_phone.is_primary=1)
 LEFT JOIN civicrm_relationship case_relationship
 ON ( case_relationship.contact_id_a = civicrm_case_contact.contact_id AND case_relationship.contact_id_b = 4197
      AND case_relationship.case_id = civicrm_case.id )

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_relationship_type case_relation_type
 ON ( case_relation_type.id = case_relationship.relationship_type_id
      AND case_relation_type.id = case_relationship.relationship_type_id )

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_case_type c_type
 ON civicrm_case.case_type_id = c_type.id

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group cog_status
 ON cog_status.name = 'case_status'

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value cov_status
 ON ( civicrm_case.status_id = cov_status.value
      AND cog_status.id = cov_status.option_group_id )
 WHERE (1) AND  civicrm_case_contact.contact_id IN( 1502 )
 AND civicrm_case.id IN( 41)
 AND civicrm_case.is_deleted     = 1  GROUP BY case_id  ORDER BY case_scheduled_activity_date ASC 1 [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 39]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: syntax error" code=-2 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="SELECT civicrm_case.id as case_id, civicrm_case.subject as case_subject, civicrm_contact.id as contact_id, civicrm_contact.sort_name as sort_name, civicrm_phone.phone as phone, civicrm_contact.contact_type as contact_type, civicrm_contact.contact_sub_type as contact_sub_type, t_act.activity_type_id, c_type.title as case_type, civicrm_case.case_type_id as case_type_id, cov_status.label as case_status, cov_status.label as case_status_name, t_act.status_id, civicrm_case.start_date as case_start_date, case_relation_type.label_b_a as case_role, t_act.desired_date as case_scheduled_activity_date, t_act.id as case_scheduled_activity_id, t_act.act_type_name as case_scheduled_activity_type_name, t_act.act_type AS case_scheduled_activity_type  FROM civicrm_case
                  INNER JOIN civicrm_case_contact ON civicrm_case.id = civicrm_case_contact.case_id
                  INNER JOIN civicrm_contact ON civicrm_case_contact.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id  INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT case_id, act.id, activity_date_time AS desired_date, activity_type_id, status_id, aov.name AS act_type_name, aov.label AS act_type
  FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM civicrm_view_case_activity_upcoming
      ORDER BY activity_date_time ASC, id ASC
      ) AS upcomingOrdered
    ) AS act
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group aog ON aog.name='activity_type'
  LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value aov ON ( aov.option_group_id = aog.id AND aov.value = act.activity_type_id )
) AS t_act

        ON t_act.case_id = civicrm_case.id
 LEFT JOIN civicrm_phone ON (civicrm_phone.contact_id = civicrm_contact.id AND civicrm_phone.is_primary=1)
 LEFT JOIN civicrm_relationship case_relationship
 ON ( case_relationship.contact_id_a = civicrm_case_contact.contact_id AND case_relationship.contact_id_b = 4197
      AND case_relationship.case_id = civicrm_case.id )

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_relationship_type case_relation_type
 ON ( case_relation_type.id = case_relationship.relationship_type_id
      AND case_relation_type.id = case_relationship.relationship_type_id )

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_case_type c_type
 ON civicrm_case.case_type_id = c_type.id

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_group cog_status
 ON cog_status.name = 'case_status'

 LEFT JOIN civicrm_option_value cov_status
 ON ( civicrm_case.status_id = cov_status.value
      AND cog_status.id = cov_status.option_group_id )
 WHERE (1) AND  civicrm_case_contact.contact_id IN( 1502 )
 AND civicrm_case.id IN( 41)
 AND civicrm_case.is_deleted     = 1  GROUP BY case_id  ORDER BY case_scheduled_activity_date ASC 1 [nativecode=1064 ** You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 39]"]
)
```

EDIT:

I have included a screenshot of the case search options I selected to help clarify:

[image]

Comment: Can you also include the query?

Comment: How do I get the query?

Comment: I have added a screenshot of the search options I used for searching the cases. I tried various options but none of them worked if I selected "deleted". If I didn't select "deleted" it worked fine.

Comment: you can see CiviCRM log to find the query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could replicate this on 5.4.0. This is fixed at https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12560

Can you please QA after applying the [patch](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/12560.patch). And also please do post your QA results on PR.

Pradeep

Comment: Many thanks Pradeep. I applied the patch you gave and it fixed my error. I left a comment on the issue saying it worked. Is this what you meant by QA? Sorry I'm not sure what QA and PR stand for.

Comment: QA = Quality Assurance, PR = Pull Request (to pull the fix in to the main code base)